# Can I do multiple items using pandas.df.at[]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day!
I currently have a huge dataset, so for the sake of simplicity, let's use this example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],
                  index=[4, 5, 6], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

And I would like to do this for all the items in column A

```
df.at[4, 'A'] = 100
df.at[5, 'A'] = 100
df.at[6, 'A'] = 100
```

Is there an easier way instead of doing 3 lines? I can't use iloc because it jacks the run time way up because of the size of my dataset.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe pyspark is the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is specifically designed to handle a **single value**.

> **DataFrame.at**
>
> Access a **single value** for a row/column label pair. Similar to `loc`, in that both provide label-based lookups. Use at if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series.

You need to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[[4, 5, 6], 'A'] = 100
```

Or, in this particular case you can replace **all values** with:

```
df['A'] = 100
```

output:

```
     A   B   C
4  100   2   3
5  100   4   1
6  100  20  30
```

Comment: Don't iloc and loc create a new df and swap out the content? When I ran iloc, the run time was awful. Wonder if loc will have the same problem

Comment: If you want to replace the whole column, use `df['A'] = 100`. How many rows do you have and how long does it take.